# Do I need to rekey SSL if I move my server from one place to another?

Tags: ssl

I have an existing ssl for a particular domain. Now we are planning to move the server to a different location with the same domain name. Can I just copy the SSL from the existing one or I still need to rekey in? Also I read there's some information that must be matched with the original one, how do I get this info back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need to rekey. All you need to do is copy over your certificate file and your private key to the new server and configure it in the same manner as your old server. The actual implementation of this is impossible to say without listing your server technology.

Answer (score 1):

**Nope !**

The key is you're certificate, so where ever you take it. 
it will represent you.

[Managing Signing Certificates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ec2-cli-managing-certs.html)

[Update the SSL Certificate for Your Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-update-ssl-cert.html)